# Having trouble running python in Rstudio with r markdown

Tags: python, rstudio, r-markdown

I need to run python code in a R markdown file for a presentation.

Here is the first code chunk to set up the R markdown:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

Here is the second code chunk to run python in Rstudio.

````
```{r engine = 'python', highlight=TRUE}
i=1
print(i);
```
````

The problem is that the second code chunk runs forever and does not output anything: the green status bar stays light green indefinitely.

I have installed python 3 on my computer, and Jupyter notebook runs fine.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. Works fine with RStudio 1.0.136, R 3.3.2 and up-to-date R-Packages

Comment: @J_F Thanks for the feedback. I will try on different computers.